# HTML download using tcp

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

How can i use tcp to interact with a server and download his html file into my computer? I know that first you need to preform the 3 way handshake and then to send a GET request. But what then? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

HTML text is written in the packet's Raw layer in scapy. In order to save a HTML file, simply write the pkt[Raw].load into a text file.